# How to convert Scientific Notation to Float?

Tags: python

I tried different codes but I'm stuck in this. I get the output as a scientific notation when I convert the float to a precision of 8. I need to convert this to float back so I can do further calculations.

Code:

```
order_cummulativeQuoteQty = 0.0003400
order_executedQty = 8.97
ENTRY_PRICE = f"{order_cummulativeQuoteQty / order_executedQty:0.8f}"

CTP = ENTRY_PRICE

CTP += (CTP * 2.0 / 100)

print(CTP)
```

Error:

```
CTP += (CTP * 2 / 100)  
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I convert entry price back to float but it shouldn't be scientific notation again?

Comment: "scientific notation" is **not a type**. That is merely how `float` objects decide to print that, which doesn't matter to what you are trying to accomplish. If you want the final result to print in a particular way, use formatting to accomplish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should leave `ENTRY_PRICE` as a `float` for doing your further arithmetic, only convert to `str` for printing purposes.

```
order_cummulativeQuoteQty = 0.0003400
order_executedQty = 8.97

ENTRY_PRICE = order_cummulativeQuoteQty / order_executedQty

CTP = ENTRY_PRICE
CTP += (CTP * 2.0 / 100)

print(f'{ENTRY_PRICE:0.8f}')
print(f'{CTP:0.8f}')
```

Output

```
0.00003790
0.00003866
```

Comment: That's right! I want to pass ENTRY_PRICE as a float number with a precision of 8 into a function that requires it to be float and 8 precision. That's my intent... how would I do that?

Comment: @Cassano  `round(ENTRY_PRICE, 8)`

Comment: @MikeM, output is 3.79e-05

Comment: @Cassano Yes, that's just the way it is printed. If it was printed as `0.00003790`, it's still a float with the same value. You seem to be confusing a particular string representation with the value of the float itself.

Comment: How do I convert this number to decimals, but usable as float?

Comment: @Cassano again, **you seem to fundamentally misunderstand**, they way the `float` object is printed is *irrelevant*. You can print it however you want using some custom formatting. There is **no difference** between `3.79e-05` and `0.0000379`. *There is nothing to convert*

Comment: I am using that float number in quantity for a Binance order, and this is the error I get: APIError(code=-1100): Illegal characters found in parameter 'quantity'; legal range is '^([0-9]{1,20})(\.[0-9]{1,20})?$'

Because it has scientific notation in it... and it is unaccepted as a number, I need it to be in decimals... that's what I mean but it should be float.